# AWS Elastic Beanstalk / NodeJS / Nginx Error: Keep getting 502 bad gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, multer, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my web application for several times, and it went well.

but since yesterday deployment, I'm keep getting 502 Bad Gateway, whenever I try to get my website.

I terminated my app from AWS elastic beanstalk and recreated, but still getting 502 bad gateway.

here's my nodejs.log:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/app/current/config/awsconfig.json'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:642:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:510:33)
    at Object.readFileSync (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:97:26)
    at Config.loadFromPath (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:409:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/server.js:14:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
fs.js:642
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
```

and this is the part in my server.js that related to nodejs error log:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const template = require("./public/template");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const _ = require("lodash");
const uuidv1 = require("uuid/v1");

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const multer = require("multer");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");

// Image Upload
AWS.config.loadFromPath(path.join(__dirname, "/config/awsconfig.json"));
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3,
    bucket: "hackingdeal",
    key: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, new Date().valueOf() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    },
    acl: "public-read-write"
  })
});
```

FYI, "server.js" file is located in root dir("./server.js") and awsconfig.json is located in "./config/awsconfig.json"

I made a .gitignore to ignore "config/awsconfig.json".
I also created a .ebignore but I didn't contained "config/awsconfig.json" so my elastic beanstalk could find and read "config/awsconfig.json" file.

This is my nginx/error.log:

```
2018/10/20 23:32:05 [error] 8103#0: *96 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 110.12.50.169, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "hackingdeal-env.4wgwkb9tdv.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2018/10/20 23:32:05 [error] 8103#0: *96 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 110.12.50.169, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/favicon.ico", host: "hackingdeal-env.4wgwkb9tdv.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://hackingdeal-env.4wgwkb9tdv.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2018/10/20 23:48:00 [error] 12936#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 110.12.50.169, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "hackingdeal.com"
2018/10/20 23:48:01 [error] 12936#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 110.12.50.169, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/favicon.ico", host: "hackingdeal.com", referrer: "http://hackingdeal.com/"
```

hackingdeal.com is my website. I connected that domain to my Elastic Beanstalk by using Route53 service, making alias.

The thing is,
My app runs successfully on localhost.

My app run successfully right after when I deployed "server.js" with Image upload statements(using AWS S3 and multer/multerS3 thing: See upper code block"

But from yesterday, it keep returns 502 bad gateway.

I'm totally lost, I don't know where to start, or where to find my problem.
please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have to read the logs to understand better your problem, but it seems that you try to load your configuration from the file `/config/awsconfig.json` in here

```
// Image Upload
AWS.config.loadFromPath(path.join(__dirname, "/config/awsconfig.json"));
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3,
    bucket: "hackingdeal",
    key: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, new Date().valueOf() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    },
    acl: "public-read-write"
  })
});
```

So, you must upload this file to your ELB. In fact, that's the problem logged in `nodejs.log`

Comment: I actually have /config/awsconfig.json in my dir and I didn't ignored it in .ebignore.

So why my eb deploy ignores my config/awsconfig.json and not upload it?

Is there anyway I can upload the file manually? or at least check whether the file exist on elastic beanstalk?

Comment: Yes there is! You will have to connect to your EC2 instance(See in https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2 which is and how to connect) via ssh and check that the file exists. I'm plenty sure that it is not being uploaded in your ELB bundle, you'll have to check why. Ask if you need more info!

Comment: I checked and awsconfig.json is already on my eb ec2 instance. 

I'm lost again..

Comment: You're saying that '/var/app/current/config/awsconfig.json' is there and exists on the EC2 of your ELB? Then the nodejs.log is lying? xD